# Convert List of Lists into Tuple

Tags: haskell

How can I convert a list of lists `[[a]]` into a tuple `([a], [a])`?

Example:

input: `[[1], [2,3,4]]`

output: `([1], [2,3,4])`

Comment: And what's the desired output for: `[]`; `[[1]]`; `[[1], [2], [3]]`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about pattern matching?

```
convert :: [[a]] -> Maybe ([a], [a])
convert [x, y] = Just (x, y)
convert _      = Nothing
```

The `Maybe` is just to handle the case where we don't have exactly two elements in our list.

Comment: Alternatively, he can just ignore all but the first two elements. He would then need to have default behavior for zero or one elements.